# Second level subcategory

Tags: categories, loop, php

I'm trying to get anoter level subcategory to show in my select option.

I've managed to get one... how can i get the other?

```
<?php
    $taxonomies = array(CUSTOM_CAT_TYPE);
    $args = array('orderby' => 'count', 'hide_empty' => 0);

    $myterms = get_terms($taxonomies, $args);
    $output = "<select class=\"select\" name='select_cat' title=\"Select Category\">";
    $output .= "<option value=''>Selecteer Rubriek</option>";


    foreach ($myterms as $cate)
        {                       
        if($cate->parent == 0)
            {
            $catename = "";
            $catename = $cate->name;
            $output .='<option disabled="disabled" value="'.$cate->term_id.'">'.$catename. '</option>';
                foreach ($myterms as $subcate)
                    {
                    if($subcate->parent == $cate->term_id)
                        {                                   
                        $catename = "";
                        $catename = $subcate->name;
                        $output .='<option value="'.$subcate->term_id.'">'.'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$catename.'</option>';
                            foreach ($subcate as $subsubcate)
                                {
                                if($subsubcate->parent == $cate->term_id)
                                    {                                   
                                    $catename = "";
                                    $catename = $subsubcate->name;
                                    $output .='<option value="'.$subsubcate->term_id.'">'.'&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'.$catename.'</option>';

                                    }
                                }
                        }
                    }
                }
        }


    $output .="</select>";
    echo $output;

    ?>
```

Any ideas?! Or perhaps a better way to get where I want to be! :)

Comment: Your code generates some `Notice`s but seems to work. What _exactly_ is the problem and _how_ exactly is it WordPress specific?

Comment: Well it works for 1 level subcategory, but i need to get another leven of subcategories. 

cat
- sub cat
-- sub sub cat

I'm using it in a advanced search i'm trying to build for my wordpress theme and uses a custom category (ads)

Comment: Ok. I get it. Try `var_dump($myterms);`. You will notice that the output is one dimensional. You will need to convert that one dimensional array into a multidimensional (nested) one before you can `foreach` over it like you are trying to do. That is a PHP question though. Search ["convert flat array to nested"](https://www.google.com/search?q=convert+flat+array+to+nested).

Comment: I've done the var_dump. You can see the results here: http://takchitaplanet.nl/test-page/. I'm kinda new to PHP and looked into the flat array to nested... But whatever i try, I won't get a nice tree structure. Where to go from here?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution! :)

```
$taxonomies = array(CUSTOM_CAT_TYPE);
        foreach($taxonomies as $tax)
         {
             $args = array(
                  'orderby'         => 'name',
                  'show_count'      => 1,
                  'pad_counts'      => 1,
                  'hierarchical'    => 1,
                  'hide_empty'      => 0,
                  'taxonomy'        => $tax,
                );

             wp_dropdown_categories( $args );
         }
```

Thanks for helping out!

Comment: Please accept your answer so the question is no longer considered unanswered; click the check mark under the vote arrows on the left.